# property_tree: cannot set a default property value?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

The code below reads a property from an ini file. However, I want the property to have a default value. I do this with `put`, before reading the ini file, and then retrieving the property with `get`.

This works fine if the default isn't required, and the program outputs `testval is 2`. However, if I comment out the entry in the ini file (as shown), the program outputs `No such node (foo.bar)`. In other words, `pt.put` is not setting the default value. Any ideas why? I'm on Boost 105300.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

int main() {
   boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
   int testval = 0;

   try {
      pt.put("foo.bar", 1);               // set a default value
      boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini("test.ini", pt);

      testval = pt.get<int>("foo.bar");

   } catch(boost::property_tree::ptree_error const& e) {
      std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
      return 1;
   }

   std::cout << "testval is " << testval << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

And `test.ini` is:

```
[foo]
;bar = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation for `read_ini()`:

> Clears existing contents of property tree. In case of error the property tree unmodified.

So whatever you do beforehand doesn't matter.

Comment: But if I put the `pt.put` *after* the `read_ini`, the value in the ini file is always ignored, and I always get `testval is 1`...?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about the use of default values.

As is now:
If you change the value of `foo.bar` to 1 before reading the file, reading the file will overwrite `foo.bar` to the contents read from the file.  If you comment out `bar=2` in the ini file, `foo.bar` has no value.

If you change the value of put to 1 after read_ini, it is normal that the value from that point on is 1.  `put()` sets the value of `foo.bar` to 1.

If what you want is set a default value for `get()` to return when `foo.bar` is not defined, you specify the default value in the call to `get()` as in:

```
testval = pt.get<int>("foo.bar", 1);  // gets foo.bar from pt, or 1 if not found.
```

You can omit the `<int>` type in 2 parameters calls to `get()`, since that gives it a type to work with, so this is equivalent to the call above:

```
testval = pt.get("foo.bar", 1);
```

Comment: The problem with the default version of `get` is that you have no way of knowing if (a) `foo.bar` is not present in the ini file, which is a valid allowable condition, or (b) `foo.bar` *is* present, but has a value which can't be parsed as an int, which must be flagged as an error. So, unless I've misunderstood, this version of `get` is useless.

Comment: The idea of a default value is to get a value if not defined in the file.  If you have a different definition of default value, you will have a hard time getting an answer for your question.  This version of get is useful in the sense that one would expect get("foo.bar", 1) to always return an int.  If you want to know if it's not an int, or not there use get<int>("foo.bar"), but then, why do you overwrite what was in the file?

Comment: Agree with your definition of default. The problem is that `property_tree` must be responsible for *all* of (1) reading a key/val from the ini file, (2) providing a default if the key *isn't* in the file, and (3) confirming that the value is well-formed if the key *is* in the file. Using the default vesion of `get` only gives you 1 and 2. If the user mistakenly enters `a` instead of `1` in the ini file, and you use default `get`, you end up silently ignoring the user's error and using a default value, so I don't believe that default `get` is useful.

Comment: property_tree was not built as a file validator.  It's designed as a tree of values for program settings.  That's why file loading and saving are separate from the class. If you want to do type validation on the contents of the ini file, you'll have to write the code to do it, read all values as string and parse/validate from there.

Comment: No, but it *was* built as a data validator, hence it throws `ptree_bad_data` if bad data in a file does not parse correctly. The problem is bad design: there appears to be no way to deal with real-world ini file usage unless you are prepared to catch `ptree_bad_path` and deal with default values for missing keys yourself, *and* you also catch `ptree_bad_data`, and then inform the user that their ini file is incorrect. Unless you walk the tree and check everything yourself, which is harder than just writing the parser in the first place. Still, +1, thanks for taking the trouble to reply.

Comment: I personally use property_tree for reading/writing both xml and json,   sometimes to convert between the two.  It works great for me.  I simply treat invalid data as non-existent, and use almost exclusively the non-throwing get(), often with 0/empty string for a default value. json output is problematic, and requires some post-treatment, but the cost is minimal compared to the ease of use of the library.